# Does Jailbreak have any impacts to iOS development?

Tags: ios, ios4, jailbreak

It is very easy to jailbreak ios device today, but I am not going to figure out how to do that here.

I want to ask , is there any influence for normal ios development if the test devices are jailbreaked ?

My simple answer will be "NO".

But I am not sure what is really happened for jailbreak devices. So question here for more serious answers. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

there is one big problem that I've took more than a week to figure out:

**inAppPurchase development doesn't work on JB devices** (it gives InvalidProductIDs for all inApps)

(some reports say it's for JB with AppSync installed)

Comment: That is a big issue if true. But my previous experience confirmed no issues for IAP. Is that new ?

Comment: maybe, I'm new to IAP. It could be XCode4. But the thing is my JB iPhone returns all product IDs as invalid where the non-JB ipod touch and ipad work fine.

Comment: You have to submit an app to the AppStore for the IAP to be registered. If you are developing an app for JB you likely would be doing so because it violets some term for AppStore submission, therefore your IAP's would not be registered with the AppStore and be unavailable. Can anyone confirm this understanding?

Comment: Flash84x, not it has nothing to do with that. I'm talking about normal AppStore apps, not JB apps. When you create a "normal" app and want to test the registered IAP it doesn't seem to work on some JB devices (the sandbox IAP testing). It's probable (though i Don't know for sure) that the final version when the app is released at the AppStore works fine on JB devices, the problem is just with the firing up by XCode of the IAP sandbox environment on JB devices used for development testing

Comment: I cant stress this enough. If you are developing apps with IAP then you will pull your hair out if you have a JB device. You are guaranteed to get invalidProductIds per xfze's answer.

Answer (score 2):

Basically, jailbreaking doesn't have any negative impacts at first glance, at the "works - doesn't work" level. Being a jailbroken developer myself, I can confirm that practically everything that (technically) works on a non-jailbroken device works on a jailbroken one too. Jailbreaking doesn't abandon APIs, doesn't remove software or system components that are needed for running an official application. It only brings **additional** facilities and features to extend the opportunities of developers (and thus that of users as well).

However, given that jailbroken systems are almost completely open, **there are security-related considerations to be made.** Specifically:

1. Your app can be cracked. And by some people, it will. Be aware of it. There is (was) Install0us, there's In-App Purchase cracker, etc. If you don't care, that's just fine, though: only a small portion of iOS users jailbreak their devices, and ***not each and every jailbreaker is a pirate whose only intention is to steal your app!***
2. Sensitive data can be obtained from the device. If you aren't careful enough, two possible things may happen. Either you store some sensitive user data on the filesystem ([even the Keychain is insecure on jailbroken devices!](https://github.com/ptoomey3/Keychain-Dumper)) and somebody else can view it (effectively enabling identity theft), or your app can be hacked (imagine if you store the score of a user in a game in a plist file, and the user simply overwrites the value in the plist to cheat).
3. The behavior of your application can easily be altered using the MobileSubstrate framework - something that you may or may not want :)

All in all: beware of cheaters and crackers, but still don't punish innocent users! Popups saying "This app doesn't run on jailbroken devices" are unfair and decrease your reputation as a developer.

Answer (score 1):

It depends what is installed, if you start adding some of the packages that are hooks of the foundation services you could possibly see some strange/unpredictable activity. Other than that I think you should be fine, the JB community all develop and test their apps on JB devices so I would think generally you are fine.

Answer (score 0):

It only won't work if you have installed something that would effect any frameworks or services as @Flash84x said.

Apart from that you are fine.

Answer (score 0):

Basic development work, just like any other device and so it should be safe to use it. The problem is that the jailbreak (not tweaks, the jb itself) modifies some core components of the system (namely some subtle sandbox things). It can happen that things that shouldn't work at all suddenly work on jailbroken devices because of these changes (not to talk about all the tweaks you could have installed that can change lots of things).

So, you can definitely use a jailbroken device to **develop** (after all not everybody can afford a dedicated device for development), but be sure to thoroughly **test** your app on a vanilla device or you can have bad surprises.

@H2CO3 I can't comment yet, but I think you missed the point: he didn't ask about running apps on jailbroken devices, but to **test** apps on jailbroken devices (which is a pretty bad idea).

Comment: Why would it be a "pretty bad idea"? As I stated: nothing is lost when you test on a jailbroken device.

Comment: Because there are things (the first thing that cames to mind is unsigned code execution, but that is pretty hard to trigger accidentally. I remember there are others, though) that shouldn't work but they indeed work correctly. There are mentions to this in the iOS Hacker's Handbook if I recall correctly.

Comment: "it's good practice to test on a vanilla device" **is not equivalent** with "it's bad practice to test on a jailbroken device". Unsigned code execution: 1. it doesn't generally work, not even on a jailbroken system. Why do you think `ldid` has been invented for? 2. Why would there be any attempt in an official application to run unsigned code?

Comment: That's why I said "the first thing that cames to mind" and "that is pretty hard to trigger accidentally". And it does work if you load a (even properly with Apple cert) signed binary and then create a rw+x memory page and execute it. This shouldn't work at all, starting from creating an executable memory page.

Comment: And anyway stating that my answer is wrong doesn't make your answer correct. ;) What I'm saying is that your answer is from the wrong point of view: you're saying that "everything that [...] works on a non-jailbroken device works on a jailbroken one too" but the question asks for the opposite thing, and "everything that works on a jailbroken device works on a jailed one too" is definitely a wrong assumption to make.